# If $ax+by = a^n + b^n$ then $\left[\frac{x}{b}\right]+\left[\frac{y}{a}\right]=\left[\frac{a^{n-1}}{b}\right]+\left[\frac{b^{n-1}}{a}\right]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let a,b,n be positive integers such that $(a,b) = 1$.
> Prove that if $(x,y)$ is a solution of the equation $ax+by = a^n + b^n$ then
> $$\left[\frac{x}{b}\right]+\left[\frac{y}{a}\right]=\left[\frac{a^{n-1}}{b}\right]+\left[\frac{b^{n-1}}{a}\right]$$

So I was trying this question which is a Romania TST problem.

$$ax+by=a^n+b^n\implies a^n-ax=b^n-by\implies \frac{a^n-ax}{ab}=\frac{b^n-by}{ba}$$

$$\frac{a^{n-1}-x}{b}=\frac{b^{n-1}-y}{a}\implies \frac{a^{n-1}}{b}-\frac{x}{b}=\frac{b^{n-1}}{a}-\frac{y}{a}. $$

I don't think so we can proceed more.

We also have $a(a^n-ax)=b(b^n-y)\implies a^{n-1}\equiv x\mod b, b^{n-1}\equiv y\mod a.$

Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Remark : Dividing both sides by $ab$ gives $\frac{x}{b} + \frac ya = \frac{a^{n-1}}{b} + \frac{b^{n-1}}{a}$, so the equality is true without the floors.

Comment: I believe your brackets are the floor function. If so, are $x$ and $y$ meant to be positive integers? Otherwise, if they can be reals, consider $a = 2$, $b = 3$ and $n = 2$, which gives $a^2 + b^2 = 13$, with $x = 0$ and $y = \frac{13}{3}$ being a solution. Then, $\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor = 0$ and $\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{13}{6} \rfloor = 2$, so the left side of the equation to prove is $2$. However, $\lfloor \frac{a^{n-1}}{b} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{2}{3} \rfloor = 0$ and $\lfloor \frac{b^{n-1}}{a} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{3}{2} \rfloor = 1$, so the right side is $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255983/if-axby-an-bn-then-left-fracxb-right-left-fracya-right#comment8850500_4255983), if $(x, y)$ is allowed to be any real solution, then \eqref{eq6A} will not always hold, so I'll assume that $x$ and $y$ must be integers. Also, I believe the square brackets are meant to represent the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), as I've seen being used elsewhere on this site.

Given the above, we can proceed from where you left off, i.e.,

$$a^{n-1} \equiv x \pmod{b} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$b^{n-1} \equiv y \pmod{a} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note \eqref{eq1A} means that $a^{n-1}$ and $x$ have the same remainder when divided by $b$, i.e., there's integers $i_1$, $i_2$ and $q$ where

$$a^{n-1} = i_{1}b + q, \; \; x = i_{2}b + q, \; \; 0 \le q \le b - 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Similarly with \eqref{eq2A}, there's integers $j_1$, $j_2$ and $r$ where

$$b^{n-1} = j_{1}a + r, \; \; y = j_{2}a + r, \; \; 0 \le r \le a - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq4A} in the given equation that $x$ and $y$ are a solution of gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
ax + by & = a^n + b^n \\
a(i_{2}b + q) + b(j_{2}a + r) & = a(i_{1}b + q) + b(j_{1}a + r) \\
ab(i_{2}) + aq + ab(j_{2}) + br & = ab(i_{1}) + aq + ab(j_{1}) + br \\
ab(i_{2}) + ab(j_{2}) & = ab(i_{1}) + ab(j_{1}) \\
i_{2} + j_{2} & = i_{1} + j_{1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

The equation you're asked to prove is

$$\left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor \frac{a^{n-1}}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{b^{n-1}}{a} \right\rfloor \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Using the second parts of \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq4A} in the left side of \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor \frac{i_{2}b + q}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{j_{2}a + r}{a} \right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor i_2 + \frac{q}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor j_2 + \frac{r}{a} \right\rfloor \\
& = i_2 + j_2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

while using the first parts of \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq4A} in the right side of \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left\lfloor \frac{a^{n-1}}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{b^{n-1}}{a} \right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor \frac{i_{1}b + q}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{j_{1}a + r}{a} \right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor i_1 + \frac{q}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor j_1 + \frac{r}{a} \right\rfloor \\
& = i_1 + j_1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

The above $2$ equations show, using \eqref{eq5A}, that the $2$ sides of \eqref{eq6A} are always equal to each other.

**Update:** The problem can be generalized to, for *any* fixed integers $c$ and $d$, then for all integer solutions $(x, y)$ of

$$ax + by = ac + bd \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

by following the same procedure as in your question and in my answer above, and replacing $a^{n-1}$ with $c$ and $b^{n-1}$ with $d$, we can show that

$$\left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor \frac{c}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{d}{a} \right\rfloor \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Comment: oh wow! This proof is really nice! And everything seems motivated. Really nice! I will reread it again when I try the question again tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI There's a "one-liner" proof of your final observation. It is essentially what you did, just rephrased.

Answer (score 2):

We will prove John's final observation:

> If $a, b$ are co-prime positive integers, and $ c, d, x, y$ are integers such that $ax+by = ac + bd$, then
> $$\left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor \frac{c}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{d}{a} \right\rfloor. $$

As observed by Teresa, the statement is true without the floor brackets, so with the floor brackets, we know that the values are very close.

Subtracting from $ \frac{x}{b} + \frac{y}{z} = \frac{c}{b} + \frac{d}{a}$, the observation is equivalent to demonstrating:

$$\left\{ \frac{x}{b} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{y}{a} \right\} =  \left\{ \frac{c}{b} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{d}{a} \right\}. $$

Since $ a (x-c) = b (y-d)$ and $ \gcd(a, b) = 1$, so $ b \mid x - c$, and thus $\left\{ \frac{x}{b} \right\} = \left\{ \frac{c}{b} \right\}. $ In fact, it is equal to $\frac{ x \pmod{b} } { b}$.
Likewise, $ a \mid y-d$, and thus $\left\{ \frac{y}{a} \right\} = \left\{ \frac{d}{a} \right\}$.
Adding up these equalities, we get the desired result.